# facebook connect button not showing

Tags: add-on, facebook, solspace-facebookconnect

I'm using Solspace's [Facebook Connect addon](http://www.solspace.com/docs/facebook_connect/login/) to add Facebook login to a site, but I can't work out why my Facebook connect button is not showing while using the following template code:

```
{exp:fbc:login permissions="email|publish_stream|read_stream"
    return_when_logged_in="site/home"
    return_when_logged_out="site/home"
    return_to_register="site/register"
    return_on_failure="site/fail"
}
{if fbc_logged_out == "y"}
    {fbc_login_button}
{/if}
{if fbc_logged_in == "y"}
    <a href="{path='logout'}" class="btnConnectSmall" >Your connected</a>
{/if}
```

Can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Be sure to add '{exp:fbc:prepare_page}' above the `<html>` tag of the page where you want the button to appear.